# Rails timezone - different results between localhost and production server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I've got a search for records by Date, and the results vary by a day between my localhost and the server.

Both have the same date:

Server:     `Tue  7 Apr 2015 11:04:53 MDT`
Localhost: `Tue Apr  7 11:05:40 MDT 2015`

Application.rb:

```
    config.time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
```

Query:

```
@beginning_of_week = Date.today.beginning_of_week
@behind = Section.where(trade_id: current_user.trade_id).
                        where("DATE(date) < ?", @beginning_of_week).
                        where("complete = false").
                        count
```

Both environments show the same date for @beginning_of_week - `2015-04-06`

Any ideas how I can further trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.today` should not be used, because it completely ignores time zones. Always use `Time.zone.today` or `Date.current` instead.

Comment: To clarify this: `Time.zone.today.beginning_of_week` would get you the beginning of week in MDT, whereas `Date.today` gets you the beginning of week in the server's local time, whatever that may be. With queries like this one, Active Record isn't smart enough to figure out what you actually intend.

Comment: Thanks everyone I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but you seem fairly confident.  HUGE help!

Comment: I have one more question while we are on the issue - I get this output in my console on localhost - can I ignore it?  warning: :database_timezone option must be :utc or :local - defaulting to :local